# Adding stemming to my schema.xml file doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I'm trying to setup [Websolr](http://www.websolr.com/) on my [Heroku app](http://addons.heroku.com/websolr). I'm following the [instructions in the Heroku docs](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/websolr). I've got the initial setup working fine.

In development:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > Note.search { keywords 'grit' }.results.length
 => 3
```

I am trying to add stemming. I updated the relevant part of my schema.xml file to this:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">

  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>

</fieldType>
```

I then reindexed:

```
$ rake sunspot:reindex
```

But it doesn't seem to work at all:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > Note.search { keywords 'gri' }.results.length
 => 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not familiar with Websolr. Do you have access to the regular Solr admin pages?

Comment: Are you updating the schema.xml on the Websolr page, or in the solr directory within your rails app?  Websolr does not use the local solr config files—it has its own hosted versions that you access through their webadmin

Comment: Sorry, should have made this more clear in the question. At the moment I'm just trying to get stemming working in development. Everything you see in the question is in development. So Websolr isn't involved (at this point).

Comment: @Karl - Yep can access Solr admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two ideas for you here:

Firstly, you didn't mention whether you were restarting Solr after changing your `schema.xml`. So: are you restarting Solr so your changes can take effect? :)

Next, I am wondering if the term `grit` would even qualify to have its `t` removed under the Porter stemming algorithm. You would need to have a close read of the [PorterStemmer algorithm](http://tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer/) to be sure. But you may also try some more obvious examples (say, `writing` to `write`).

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the Porter stemming algorithm. writing to write works fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Anytime! Feel free to send me questions you have about websolr itself once you get into production :)

Comment: Also it occurs to me that if you're expecting 'gri' to match 'grit' you should look at the EdgeNGram filter factory.